# Get the Zip Code of the Current Location - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, location

Is there a method or some way to display the zip code of the current location? Maybe through CLLocationManager or through coordinate points (latitude, longitude).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get current location from user in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `MKReverseGeocoder` class from MapKit framework.