# How can I get current location from user in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager, currentlocation

How can I get the current location from user in iOS?

Comment: please!! see **Rayn Wu's** answer if you looking for iOS 6

Answer (score 343, accepted):

The answer of RedBlueThing worked quite well for me. Here is some sample code of how I did it.

#### Header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface yourController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@end
```

#### MainFile

In the init method

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Callback function

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

### iOS 6

In iOS 6 the delegate function was deprecated. The new delegate is

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Therefore to get the new position use

```
[locations lastObject]
```

### iOS 8

In iOS 8 the permission should be explicitly asked before starting to update location

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

You also have to add a string for the [`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26) or [`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26) keys to the app's Info.plist. Otherwise calls to `startUpdatingLocation` will be ignored and your delegate will not receive any callback.

And at the end when you are done reading location call stopUpdating location at suitable place.

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: +1 thanks for posting a simple code snippet to compliment the accepted answer

Comment: Be careful with this example, these property values lead to higher battery consumption.

Comment: IMPORTANT: You also need to "stopUpdatingLocations" else the delegate method will be called every time the user changes its location. Thus above mentioned battery problem and also if there is another method being triggered in this delegate method, it will be kept calling. Happy Coding Guys!! Cheers!!

Comment: You are the type of user that makes StackOverflow great.  Code snippets are exemplary and I hope more people include them with their answers.

Comment: Very nice answer, helped me with exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: For iOS 8.0+ you have to include following keys in Info.plist of your project: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` if you are using `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` if you are using `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`. Also to support iOS 6.0+ to iOS 7.0+ include key `NSLocationUsageDescription` or 'Privacy - Location Usage Description'. More info on link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: @vijay Did you add the key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` ? It is the popup that asks the user to grant permission. Without it the box would not open and it wont throw any error as well

Comment: you should use `if ([self.locationManager responseSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])` instead of checking `systemVersion` ....

Comment: If you don't see `didUpdateLocations` getting called, be sure that your `CLLocationManagerInstance` is not getting deallocated. Try holding it in an instance variable in your delegate class

Answer (score 80):

In iOS 6, the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

is deprecated.

Use following code instead

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"lat%f - lon%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

For iOS 6~8, the above method is still necessary, but you have to handle authorization.

```
_locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0 &&
    [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse
    //[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways
   ) {
     // Will open an confirm dialog to get user's approval 
    [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; 
    //[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
} else {
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //Will update location immediately 
}
```

This is the delegate method which handle user's authorization

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    switch (status) {
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
        NSLog(@"User still thinking..");
    } break;
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied: {
        NSLog(@"User hates you");
    } break;
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways: {
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; //Will update location immediately
    } break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: should this not be `[locations lastObject]`?

Comment: I tried the exact same steps mentioned above. But I get "User still thinking" printed in the console. So, does it mean the app is not authorised to use location? If yes, how do I allow the app to use location. Please help.

Answer (score 61):

You use the [CoreLocation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123) to access location information about your user.  You will need to instantiate a [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125) object and call the asynchronous [startUpdatingLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) message.  You will get callbacks with the user's location via the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124) that you supply.

Answer (score 31):

#### Try this Simple Steps....

**NOTE:** Please check device location latitude & logitude if you are using simulator means. By defaults its none only.

**Step 1:** Import `CoreLocation` framework in .h File

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

**Step 2:** Add delegate CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
```

**Step 3:** Add this code in class file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self CurrentLocationIdentifier]; // call this method
}
```

**Step 4:** Method to detect current location

```
//------------ Current Location Address-----
-(void)CurrentLocationIdentifier
{
    //---- For getting current gps location
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    //------
}
```

**Step 5:** Get location using this method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!(error))
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Detected\n");
             NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
             NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
             NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
             NSString *Area = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.locality];
             NSString *Country = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:placemark.country];
             NSString *CountryArea = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", Area,Country];
             NSLog(@"%@",CountryArea);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error %@", error);
             NSLog(@"\nCurrent Location Not Detected\n");
             //return;
             CountryArea = NULL;
         }
         /*---- For more results 
         placemark.region);
         placemark.country);
         placemark.locality); 
         placemark.name);
         placemark.ocean);
         placemark.postalCode);
         placemark.subLocality);
         placemark.location);
          ------*/
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

### In Swift (for iOS 8+).

**Info.plist**

First things first. You need to add your descriptive string in the info.plist file for the keys `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` depending on what kind of service you are requesting

**Code**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    let manager: CLLocationManager
    var locationManagerClosures: [((userLocation: CLLocation) -> ())] = []
    
    override init() {
        self.manager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        self.manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    //This is the main method for getting the users location and will pass back the usersLocation when it is available
    func getlocationForUser(userLocationClosure: ((userLocation: CLLocation) -> ())) {
        
        self.locationManagerClosures.append(userLocationClosure)
        
        //First need to check if the apple device has location services availabel. (i.e. Some iTouch's don't have this enabled)
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            //Then check whether the user has granted you permission to get his location
            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
                //Request permission
                //Note: you can also ask for .requestWhenInUseAuthorization
                manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Restricted || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Denied {
                //... Sorry for you. You can huff and puff but you are not getting any location
            } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
                // This will trigger the locationManager:didUpdateLocation delegate method to get called when the next available location of the user is available
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //MARK: CLLocationManager Delegate methods
    
    @objc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedAlways || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        //Because multiple methods might have called getlocationForUser: method there might me multiple methods that need the users location.
        //These userLocation closures will have been stored in the locationManagerClosures array so now that we have the users location we can pass the users location into all of them and then reset the array.
        let tempClosures = self.locationManagerClosures
        for closure in tempClosures {
            closure(userLocation: newLocation)
        }
        self.locationManagerClosures = []
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
self.locationManager = LocationManager()
self.locationManager.getlocationForUser { (userLocation: CLLocation) -> () in
            print(userLocation)
        }
```

Comment: i believe there is a switch() in swift for cases like this :^)

Comment: `self.locationManager = LocationManager()`
use this line in the viewDidLoad method so that ARC does not remove the instance and popup for location disappears too quickly.

Answer (score 12):

The Xcode Documentation has a wealth of knowledge and sample apps - check the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497).

The [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801) sample project illustrates the effects of modifying the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager)'s different accuracy settings

Answer (score 3):

iOS 11.x Swift 4.0
Info.plist needs these two properties

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We're watching you</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Watch Out</string>
```

And this code ... making sure of course your a CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

// MARK location Manager delegate code + more

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        print("User still thinking")
    case .denied:
        print("User hates you")
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .restricted:
        print("User dislikes you")
    }
```

And of course this code too which you can put in viewDidLoad().

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestLocation()
```

And these two for the requestLocation to get you going, aka save you having to get out of your seat :)

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(locations)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this service](https://github.com/williamFalcon/WFLocationService.git) I wrote to handle everything for you.

This service will request the permissions and handle dealing with the CLLocationManager so you don't have to.

Use like this:

```
LocationService.getCurrentLocationOnSuccess({ (latitude, longitude) -> () in
    //Do something with Latitude and Longitude

    }, onFailure: { (error) -> () in

      //See what went wrong
      print(error)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 5, here's a quick short class to get the location:

```
class MyLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let manager: CLLocationManager

    override init() {
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // do something with locations
    }
}
```

Comment: import CoreLocation 
is also needed