# How to get the user's current location by code in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, location, currentlocation

I want to get the user's current location from my iPhone app. I want to show the user's current location like country name, latitude, longitude information in my app. And also i want to show the location in Google map also. I have tried Google search also, but can't get the exact answer. I have get the info that was to use `CLLocationManager` in my app to track the location. How do i use this? I have download one sample app from Apple Documents. Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html

Can you please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get current location from user in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I have get the info that was to use `CLLocationManager` in my app to track the location. How do i use this?

in .h file

```
#include <CoreLocation/CLLocationManagerDelegate.h>
#include <CoreLocation/CLError.h>
#include <CoreLocation/CLLocation.h>
#include <CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.h>

CLLocationManager   * myLocationManager;

CLLocation          * myLocation;
```

in .m file :-

```
    -(void)findMyCurrentLocation
    {           

    self.myLocationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    [[self myLocationManager] setDelegate:self ];
    [myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    double latitude=34.052234;
    double longitude=-118.243685;

    CLLocation *defaultLocation =[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
    [self setMyLocation:defaultLocation];
    [defaultLocation release];

    if( [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] )
    {   
        NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled....");
        locationServicesEnabled=TRUE;
        UIAlertView *alert = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" 
                                                         message:@"Fetching your current location." 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil ];
        [alert release];
    }
    else
    {   
        NSLog( @"Location Services Are Not Enabled...." );
        locationServicesEnabled=FALSE;
        UIAlertView *alert = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" 
                                                         message:@"Location service is not enable. Please enable it from settings." 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil ];
        [alert release];
     }

        }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
      [self setMyLocation:newLocation];

    NSString *tempLat = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.6f" , (newLocation.coordinate.latitude) ];
    NSString *tempLong= [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.6f" , (newLocation.coordinate.longitude)];

    appDelegate.curlat = tempLat;
    appDelegate.curlong = tempLong;
   }

     - (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
     {
    printf("\nerror");
    UIAlertView *alert = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                     message:@"Error while getting your current location." 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil ];

    [alert release];
     }
```

2). I want to show the user's current location like country name information in my app.

For this you can to use [Google's Reverse Geo coding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) OR [MKReverseGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Just a note, MKReverseGeocoder no longer exists you have to use CLGeocoder and use the reverseGeocode function

Answer (score 1):

this should do most of it..

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/804_Introduction_to_MapKit_Framework_for_iPhone_Development.aspx

to get the information on the location you need to use MKReverseGeocoder

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323

Answer (score 0):

First create an instance of the `MKMapView`

**To get user's latitude and longitude**:

In your `viewDidLoad`

```
[yourMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoord;

userCoord.latitude=map_view.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
userCoord.longitude=map_view.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

//NSLogging these on simulator will give you Cupertino or whatever location you set in location simulation.
```

**And for country name** you will need reversegeocoding you can look at the class reference here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323

**OR**

If MKReverseGeoCoding gets too complicated you can use Yahoo's reversegeocoder

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=%f,%f&gflags=R&appid=yourAppId, those 2 %f will be `userCoord.longitude` and `userCoord.latitude`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use CLGeoCoder. But CLGeaCoder will not provide accrurate location inforamtion outside of USA for other country like India etc. So better to use Google's Reverse Geo coding [SVGeoCoder](https://github.com/samvermette/SVGeocoder). SVGeoCoder have nice implementation to get location with goolePlaceAPI.