# Simulated Location Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

i'm trying to simulate the location with Xcode 4.5 and Iphone Simulator 6.0

i get the localeIdentifier with the following code

```
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
```

i try the app on my Iphone and my locale is IT (i'm in Rome)...when i use "Don't Simulate Location" on the Iphone Simulator my locale is US...but with other Simulated Locations i recive always US
it doesn't work...Any idea?!...are there some settings to set to use the Simulate location?!
thanks

Comment: The simulator is a bit restricted in its possibilities. Maybe that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge NSLocale does not refer to location but rather to language settings etc.
See:[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale)

If you want to retrieve the location take a look at this question:
[How can I get current location from user in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

Comment: Thanks...i needed only the localIdentifier to send the correct request to Google Shopping Server...it refers to language settings as you sad but it's ok...just have to change the language preference in Iphone simulator ;)