# Can I get the accuracy of GPS location in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I've seen Android developers get the accuracy of a GPS location. Is there a way that I can get the accuracy of my currenct GPS location in iOS?

I am using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios) answer to get my location:

```
 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 locationManager.delegate = self;
 locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
     NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
     NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, you can surely do that by using same `CLLocation` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 properties on the `CLLocation` `-horizontalAccuracy` and `-verticalAccuracy`. Most of times the accuracy is based on the hardware that you are using to get the location

Answer (score 8):

`horizontalAccuary` of `CLLocation` gives the estimated positional error in meters related to the latitude, longitude coordinate.

`verticalAccuracy` gives the estimated error related to `altitude`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` properties in `CLLocation` class. If horizontalAccuracy is a huge value you can discard the signals.

Also make sure to check the `timeStamp` with current date to ensure that the GPS signal is not cached.