# Google maps api for iOS using storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

i'm trying to add Google map to my app in map view and i want to put features like the one that in whatsapp. By providing the near places , search bar and share my current location.
Can any body help me and tell me if there is something i need to buy or request from Google or anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, to get the map running, you can follow the steps shown in [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro)

With [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) you can search for nearby places in a given position. Or you can search for locations based on a string.

To get your current location, you can see how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios).

You dont have to buy anything. Although, Google API has limitations of access. For example, The Google Places only allow you to do 1,000 requests a day.
The Google Maps SDK for iOS do not limit the request.

Here is a snippet of a code of mine to access the Google Places API.

```
NSString * key = @"PUT YOUR KEY HERE";
NSString * html_msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSString * address = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?sensor=false&key=%@&query=%@", key, html_msg];
//Create URL and Request
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse * response;
NSError * error = nil;
//Send Request
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    //Parse JSON to Dictionary
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    //Get the lat/lng of the first result
    [json[@"results"][0][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lat"] doubleValue];
    [json[@"results"][0][@"geometry"][@"location"][@"lng"] doubleValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what features are included in whatsapp, but a google search tells me that there is a Google Maps SDK, with features that should allow you to create a "highly interactive" app. It doesn't seem to cost anything, but you do need to credit Google. Here's the link to their website:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/