# CLLocationManager Not getting Location Accuracy In Cellular Network (3G)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-location

I am Having a problem In Location Accuracy Using Cellular Network.

Following are the My issues

1. Sometimes Location accuracy is very perfect in Cellular Networks(3G)
2. Sometimes Location Accuracy is Not getting perfectly Its one mile difference.
3. For WiFi Its working Very Perfectly.

Following are My code

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Please what is the problem for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cellular network location gives an approximate area were the phone existing. It is based on the service providers tower.So i recommend using gps location tracking so that you get the exact longitude and latitude of your phone.

Longitude and latitude can be used to find more details about the location like place,weather etc..

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't force the device the location trough satellite (3G or 4G)

You (the app) can only access the location the device gets (And if it have permission).

When you have highest accuracy [`kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation) it will try to get the most accuracy it can get (**First GPS**, then triangulation/network + aditional sensor data) (Not recommended, this is only for "navigation" it consumes too much energy and assumes it is plugged in).

For this please refer to the [`Core Location Constants Reference`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/index.html)

If you are outdoors you may not have exact location at first, it may take some time to get the best location available to the phone.

Please reffer to the documentation of [`CLLocationManager desiredAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy)

> When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event
>   delivered by the location service may not have the accuracy you
>   requested. The location service delivers the initial event as quickly
>   as possible. It then continues to determine the location with the
>   accuracy you requested and delivers additional events, as necessary,
>   when that data is available.