# How to give UIWebView access to current gps location

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, gps

I have a UIWebView inside my app, this loads a website which is trying to get the current gps location of the user. On Safari it presents a popup which asks if you want to give your current location to the website, on my UIWebView no such thing happens and my website is not able to get the gps location of the user. How can I accomplish this? I am new to ios developing so bear with me if this is something very easy to do, but I couldnt find an example so far.

Here is what I have so far:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *_webView;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_webView loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    if ([_webView canGoBack]) {
        [_webView goBack];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4152003/2298998

Comment: it is similar but this does not tell me how my uiwebview will get access to this information, only how i will get the location in general. but i want my uiwebview to work :-)

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas Have you got this answer? I want similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your app's info.plist and set

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription "String you want to explain why you need location."