# how to update the latitude and longitude values based on UserLocation in the url shown below?

Tags: ios

```
-(void)startParsing

{
xmlParser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=17.4297757,78.4294033&radius=500&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB2R3W5-MXd74CNVRGU30As4_Hypuq2Ysw"]];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser parse];

}
```

Comment: get current location latitude & longitude , then replace that values in url. check link to find current location of user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like

**Step-1**

> Initially get update location using  `didUpdateLocations` methods.

```
// Location Manager Delegate Methods    
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
[manager stopUpdatingLocations];
 CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
  [self startParsing:lat longi:lon];
}
```

> once you get updated locations then send the data to server

```
 -(void)startParsing:(NSString *)lati longi:(NSString *)longa
{
   NSString *stringofNewLocation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%@,%@&radius=500&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB2R3W5-MXd74CNVRGU30As4_Hypuq2Ysw",lati,longa];
xmlParser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringofNewLocation]];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser parse];

}
```