# Get user current location(lat/long) in all app state not always only when My app required without location manager delegate

Tags: ios, swift, location, health-monitoring

I am working on watch heart beat app and I want when user heart rate critical then we will get his current location in(foreground, background and terminate) and send it to our server. Is there any way through which I get user location only at that position. I don't want to update his location every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get current location from user in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

Answer (score 2):

To get user location you have to declare :

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

in your controller.

Then, in `viewDidLoad` you have to request for location and initialize the `CLLocationManager` get process :

```
// Ask for Authorisation from the User.
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 

// For use in foreground
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

You will get location in `CLLocationManagerDelegate` :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    print("locations = \(location.latitude) \(location.longitude)")
}
```

In your `info.plist` you have to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and custom alert message to show while requesting for location.

cheers...

Comment: But How can I get location when my app in terminated state

Comment: If a user terminates the app the system no longer grants it the same privileges. Background fetch operations and background location will not get executed until the user decides to start up your app again.

Comment: Please read my description I have mention it. I know we can get current location with the help of significant location update but its not update continues.