# Why latitude and longitude is showing zero in ios 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have to find the current location and i am using this code

```
 -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
return coordinate;
```

}

```
- (void)getCurrentLocation{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"Latitude  = %@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude = %@", longitude);
}
```

but latitude and longitude is coming zero? and i have called these method in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self getCurrentLocation];
[self getLocation];
```

why is it so please help me. thanks

Comment: why down vote if you know the answer then post here?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You need to use `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods to get the coordinates. You need to read the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

Comment: which method i have to use ?

Comment: @iphonic i am trying but not working tell me what to do/

Comment: What to do: Read the documentation. If you need someone to tell you, any Mac can also read the documentation to you.

Answer (score 3):

I hope , Following info can help you:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface yourController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@end
```

and add this:

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Callback function

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

You also have to add a string for the

```
[`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`]
```

Comment: no error is coming bro didupdatelocations is not executing

Comment: thank you @Suraj But it is updating again and again how to stop it or how to set timer so that after some fix time it will update

Comment: set like this--- locationManager.distanceFilter=20 ( set this value as per your requirement) ; It filters out short moves.and you get location update only when user moves greater than 20 meters.

Comment: I think, locationManager.distanceFilter=(any value);  this solve your issue....but if you want to know more about timer then use this------- NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
-(void)timerCalled
{
     NSLog(@"Timer Called");
     // Your Code
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113394/discussion-between-aakash-and-suraj-sukale).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "`CLLocationManagerDelegate`".

**Just go through this tutorial.** [How To Get the User Location in iPhone App](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/)

Here you will learn about `CoreLocation Framework`.

This is the delegate method which will return you current lat-long.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

And also make sure your app authorize to use location services.

And Also run your app on **device**, or if you want to see the result in **simulator**, follow the steps mentioned in tutorial.

**Step 1** : `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` import framework. Also add framework in your project.

**Step 2** : Make sure your view-controller implement CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
@interface MyLocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

**Step 3** : Define class instance of `CLLocationManager`

```
@implementation MyLocationViewController {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

**Step 4** :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            //iOS 8.0 onwards
            [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**Step 5** : Here is your CLLocationManagerDelegate
 method implementation

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
       NSLog(@"Longitude %.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
       NSLog(@"Latitude %.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using your method but still not showing any latitude and longitude

Comment: did you follow the tutorial step by step ?

Comment: I updated my answer. try this. And run your app on device. remove previously stored app on device. check permission of app in device too.

Comment: Welcome. If my answer helps then please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

First go to your info.plist and right click on it and select the source code option.
[image]

Then add the following lines after the `<dict>` keyword

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This App wants to Know your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This App wants to Know your location</string>
```

Without this, you can't get CLLocation working in iOS 9.0.

Now follow the instruction.

Import

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

and list the CoreLocation delegate like

```
@interface ViewController ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

Then in the viewDidLoad method add the following lines-

```
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Now implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Sorry" 
                               message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"      
                               delegate:nil 
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time for the `CLLocationManager` to get the `coordinates`. Therefore, the `CLLocationManager` uses a delegate to notify when it received the location updates. Therefore, you cannot get the result immediately. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios) post to see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wanted you to read the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html), still I am posting the solution.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     [self initLocationManager];
}


-(void)initLocationManager{

    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    if (([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {
        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Then handle the location updates in the `CLLocationManager` delegate method like below

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{

    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {


        NSLog(@"%f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude);


    }
}
```

**Update**

To make it work, you need to do two things

1. Enable `Background Modes` from `Capabilities` Tab, and choose `Location Updates`, see image below

   [image]
2. Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in Info Tab, into the plist, see image

   [image]

It will start working.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: it is not working brother not showing anything even method is not executing

Comment: -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
 this method is not executing

Comment: @aakash See my Update.

Comment: it is working now thank you very much for you help but how to stop updating    latitude and longitude again and again in 0.1millisecond

Comment: Just call [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; when you want to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it works

firstly add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` as string in `info.plist`

in .h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ExamListVC : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager * locationManager;
}
@end
```

in .m use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    locationManager . delegate = self;

    [self initLocationManager];
}

    -(void)initLocationManager
    {
        locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate=self;
        if (([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]))
        {
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }


    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
    {
        CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
        NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
        NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
        if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0)

        {
            NSLog(@"Current Coordinates are  %f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude);
            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            }
        }
```

it will give output like

> [2390:96060] Current Coordinates are 37.332331,-122.031219