# User current location delegate method not called in iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, core-location, ios11

I just installed my app in iOS 11 and run the app and get current user location. But I won't get, it is working fine in iOS 10.

Comment: Please follow below link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added both the new key `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and one of the old keys `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, locations services work fine again.