# Continues location get in simulator but not in real device after terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I was set continues location get method so continues location get in simulator, but not in real device some time we got the location but some how stop this method and again start continues location get. These all scenario in after terminated app not in foreground or background.
Please help me this issue.

I have using this library.
"https://github.com/benzamin/BBLocationManager"

Answer (score 0):

To get location continuously follow these two links...

https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

[How can I get current location from user in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

No need of Git code

Comment: Thank's for the best reply,

But i need to after app is terminated not foreground or background.