# (From an old xcode project) How can I enable location service?

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation

I have an old xcode project from iPhone4 and iPhone3GS era.
It uses location service.

When I run the app, it seems it does not get locations.
Even it does not ask "it uses your current locastion. do you allow it?"

How can I enable location service?
Note: it did not have any problems to get locations on iPhone3GS.

Thank you very much!
Have a nice weekend :)

Xcode 14.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Everything could be found in CoreLocation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation

You'll need user permission (of course) and you could want to match location with movements. If this is the case, also look for CoreMotion:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/

EDIT: Most certain you are using deprecated API's... check for different methods and ways to manage location and motion then what you are doing before.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your reply.
I found the answer here:
[How can I get current location from user in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152003/how-can-i-get-current-location-from-user-in-ios)

In iOS 8 or later the permission should be explicitly asked before starting to update location:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

This solved my problem.
Thank you very much!

Hope this helps someone with the same problem when compiling an old Xcode geolocation application. :)